# Error loading YOLO model in android - load requires a 'tags=' argument if there is more than one meta graph. Got 'tags=None'

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, tensorflow-lite

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLj5z.png)I have trained my own YOLO model with Darkflow and got the .pb file and the .meta file for license plate recognition. What i am trying now is to implement an android App that can use this model. To do so i have decided to convert it into tflite but always get this error about "tags=". I've checked the tags of my model with 'saved_model_cli show --dir=./' and i've got no tags. What should i do to fix this error ?

Comment: I'd suggest you paste the error instead of attaching an image. It will improve the readability of your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to help. You might need Ctrl+K for code formatting and it's better to post error as text

Comment: Thank you for your answers i just found that the error was due to the version of tensorflow. I was using tensorflow 2.0.1 while running the command. it worked when i downgraded to tensorflow 1.14.0